# Live data observer called before getting the data from API/Database

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, android-livedata, observers

I am using **Firebase Firestore as Database** and getting data from firestore. I am calling **categoryList** data from function from **Home Fragment-->ViewModel-->Repository(Suspend function)** and obseve the live data in MainActivity, so that I can get the list and recyclerview will be updated.
But when I call the View model function in Home Fragment and then add observer to live data, The live data observer gets called before getting the data from Firestore, hence my recyclerview gets the empty list.

**Please find the code below:**

**Repository Code:**

```
suspend fun getAllCategories():ArrayList<CategoryItem>{
        var list: ArrayList<CategoryItem> = ArrayList()
        db.collection(Constant.CATEGORY_TABEL) // DB is Firebase Firestore Instance
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                for (document in result) {
                    val data = document.toObject(CategoryItem::class.java) // adding data to model class
                    list.add(data)

                }
               
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.w("main", "Error getting documents.", exception)
            }

        return list
    }
```

**View Model Code:**

```
private var _catList = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<CategoryItem>>()
    val catList: LiveData<ArrayList<CategoryItem>> get() = _catList
fun getAllCategories(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _catList.postValue(repository.getAllCategories())
        }

    }
```

**Home Fragment Code:**

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        setupCategoryRV()

        storeViewModel.getAllCategories()
       
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
           delay(800) //If I add delay, then it works properly.
            storeViewModel.catList.observe(requireActivity(), Observer { list->
                Log.i("list size", list.size.toString())
                catAdapter.updateList(list)
            })
           
        }
}

private fun setupCategoryRV() {
        catAdapter = CategoryAdapter(this)
        binding.categoryRv.apply {
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
            hasFixedSize()
            adapter = catAdapter
        }
    }
```

If I comment out **delay(800)** code in Home fragment, it returns me empty list. Ideally Live data should notify whenever there is change in the data. 1st time its empty, but when it receives the data, it should call observer again, which is not happening here.

Please help here.

Comment: is `list.add(data)`  running ? i don't know why you think that you'll be notified more than once though, considering that `suspend fun getAllCategories():ArrayList<CategoryItem>{` is just going to get called once, this isn't a live data or a repetitive method, it's going to give you the data once and then only again when you call it, unless i'm mistaken

Comment: Yes... list.add(data) working. And it is getting the Arraylist of category Item and set it to Live data _catList in View model, which I am observing in fragment. As per the documentation, whenever there is change in Live data, observer observes it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use only one value in viewmodel and observe it.
Also initialise it with empty value this way it will not be called.
Something like following

```
private val _catList = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<CategoryItem>>()

fun getAllCategories(){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _catList.postValue(repository.getAllCategories())
    }

}
```

And set observers first in your fragment

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
   setupCategoryRV()
   
       storeViewModel.catList.observe(requireActivity(), Observer {list->
           Log.i("list size", list.size.toString())
           catAdapter.updateList(list)
       })

   storeViewModel.getAllCategories()
 }
```